# How can I enable spell checking in Gnote?

Tags: spell-checking, gnote

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I'm pretty sure the version of Gnote that came with Ubuntu 11.10 supported spell checking. However, spell checking does not appear to work in the version of Gnote that comes with Ubuntu 12.04 (8.2).

Is it possible to enable spell checking in Gnote 8.x? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's impossible.

Gnote package in Ubuntu 12.04 is build against GTK+ 3. With GTK+ 3 you can use only GTKSpell 3.0.X, but Gnote 0.8.X has no support for GTKSpell 3.0.X.